# Multiple bitcoin transactions between addresses in the same wallet

Tags: blockchain.info, coinbase.com

I have two wallets: one in coinbase and one in blockchain.info. I imported several outside addresses(created in bitaddress.org) in my blockchain.info wallet. However, sometimes when I transfer bitcoins from my coinbase wallet to my blockchain.info wallet, the transaction is followed by several (usually two) transactions within my blockchain.info addreses (in the same wallet). As if the money is being bounced off within the addresses inside the wallet. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Can you post an example? It's hard to know what you're asking without context.

Comment: Did you happen to import any private keys, using the "sweep" option? If so, it might try to keep re-sweeping any new inputs, though I am just speculating.

Answer (score 2):

Coinbase sometimes creates an address to move your bitcoin from cold storage. Any movement ie downloading to offline storage. will require a hash for the block chain/transaction  to "track" the bitcoin. Hence the appearance of transactions in the wallet.